# WordPress.com vs WordPress.org

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, wordpress.org

This question might seem a little silly but I was wondering what is the differences between WP.com and WP.org?

I know the main differences like you can't edit a them file without paying for it, you might get some ads and you get a youname.wordpress.com domain but what are the little features that make the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- WordPress.com is **web service**.
- WordPress.org is **software product**.

Think bus vs car. You can ride both, but bus is owned by someone else and what you can do with it is limited.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer is the one directly from the horse's mouth:

http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress.com is a hosted blogging service based, of course, on Wordpress. You can register and open your blog, choosing from a variety of themes. It's running the latest version of WordPress.

Wordpress.org is the site where you can download WordPress, themes and plugins and install it in your own server.

Comment: yes I know that but what features do each other have that the others don't?

Comment: I'm not sure what more you're expecting, Benny.  This answer is pretty much all you need to know.  It's not a case of "features", it's more of a case of their purpose.

Comment: Most important difference for me is that if you download the .org version, you can edit your custom css in the package you install. (be it from wordpress.org or a third party installer from bitnami.org, etc) The other two, that you mention, well, for me are quite of important. An average/advanced user might prefer the downloadable version, while somebody with less control of technical issues would be better choosing the wordpress.com solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to answer your question specifically as it's quite broadly asked. Probably the questions tagged [wordpress.com](/questions/tagged/wordpress.com) are of use.